# ¿Dónde alojar los archivos públicos en producción?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

estoy usando nodeJS para el backend y tengo la duda de dónde puedo guardar los archivos (imágenes, gifs, videos, etc.) de los usuarios, ¿los guardo en la carpeta public del proyecto o contrato un servidor aparte para alojar los archivos?

Comment: Si tu servidor tiene espacio y puedes crear bkp de ellos, supongo que no habria problema, en otro caso podrias alojarlo en otro a parte como S3 de Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

personalmente te recomendaría utilizar s3, es el que utilizo para todos mis proyectos. Solo necesitas una cuenta de aws y crear un bucket, ahí podrás guardar todos tus archivos, controlar el acceso al publico o no, y tiene varias librerías que facilitan su implementación con nodejs. 
A continuacion te anexo algunos links que pueden ayudarte:

1. Sdk Oficial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html
2. libreria para multer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3
3. Una playlist de youtube corta y detallada del uso de s3 con nodejs: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLImOJ2OqvvkBaMACVK_jhTLqRiKEDDECj